# read xml files online

Tags: python, web-services, urllib, http.client

i'm new to programing and I'm trying to accese the webservice provided in http://indicadoreseconomicos.bccr.fi.cr/indicadoreseconomicos/WebServices/wsindicadoreseconomicos.asmx?op=ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML, i've added the parameters I need to acces it but when I try to read the file in python I get 
TypeError: 'HTTPResponse' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

this is my code

```
import urllib
import http.client
import time
HEADERS={"Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"text/plain"}
HOST = "indicadoreseconomicos.bccr.fi.cr"
POST = "/indicadoreseconomicos/WebServices/wsIndicadoresEconomicos.asmx/ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicos"
data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'tcIndicador': 317,
                           'tcFechaInicio':str(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")),
                           'tcFechaFinal':str(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")),
                           'tcNombre' : 'TI1400',
                           'tnSubNiveles' : 'N'})
conn=http.client.HTTPConnection(HOST)
conn.request("POST",POST,data,headers=HEADERS)
response= conn.getresponse()
responseSTR= response.read(response)
print (response)
```

Any suggestions are apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.read()` takes an optional argument that is the number of bytes to read from the response; an integer, whole number. Now you passed the `response` object instead.

As you want to read the entire response, you should omit the argument altogether, thus:

```
response_str = response.read()
print(response_str)
```